# Why can I checkout a branch that was removed on GitHub?

Tags: git

In our GitHub repository, a coworker removed a branch named `release`. But when I run `git checkout release` locally, I always get the removed branch `release`. Same, even when I checked out another branch, deleted the `release` branch with `git branch -D release` and ran again `git checkout release`.

Is there something to fix on the GitHub repository, or shall I fix something locally?

Comment: What does `git branch --remote` output, after running `git fetch`? You might need to prune with `git fetch -p` to forget deleted remote branches.

Comment: If that branch was ever pushed to GitHub, and you pulled after that, then you have a copy of the branch too. Every git repository is complete in and of itself, unless you used a shallow clone or something.

Comment: @StephenKitt: Thanks. `git branch --remote` output `origin/release`.  Do you mean to run `git fetch -p` without additional arguments, and will it prune all the deleted remote branches?

Comment: Yes, `git fetch -p` with no additional arguments will prune all the deleted remote branches.

Comment: @StephenKitt: Do `git fetch -p` and `git push origin :release` in rudimeier's reply both forget deleted remote branches, except the former prune all and the latter prune the specified branch?

Comment: @Tim `git push origin :release` would do what your coworker probably already did. `git fetch -p` is similar to `git remote prune origin` in my answer.

Comment: @rudimeier does `git push origin :release` delete the `release` branch on GitHub, which I mentioned my coworker already deleted? Do `git fetch -p` and `git remote prune origin` clean up the tracking info within my local repository for `release` branch?

Comment: Yes, `git push origin :release` deletes the remote branch. It’s not really a good idea in this case, since (a) your colleague has already done that (possibly via the GitHub UI), and (b) if anyone else adds a new branch with the same name on the server, you’ll delete that new branch...

Comment: that's exactly why people shouldn't be allowed to go around and change history.

Comment: What do you suggest instead? @njzk2

Comment: Welcome to the world of distributed version control!

Answer (score 28):

After deleting a branch on the remote side you may still see this formerly fetched remote branch locally, see:

```
$ git branch -a
[...]
release
remotes/origin/release
[...]
```

You only removed the "release" but not "remotes/origin/release". Delete it like this:

```
$ git branch -rd origin/release
```

Or remove *all* fetched branches which do not exist on the remote side anymore:

```
$ git remote prune origin
```

Comment: Thanks. In `git branch -rd origin/release`, what does `-r` mean? Does `-d` mean the same as `-D`?  Can  `git branch -rd origin/release` be replaced with  `git branch -d remotes/origin/release`?

Comment: @Tim: From the manual; -r: `List or delete (if used with -d) the remote-tracking branches.`; -D: `Shortcut for --delete --force.`

Comment: Thanks. Can `git branch -rd origin/release` be replaced with `git branch -d remotes/origin/release`?

Comment: @Tim no `-r` refers to *remote* branches, it's needed. The local and remote branches are stored in different directories, compare  `ls -l .git/refs/heads` and `ls -l .git/refs/remotes`. You could also have a *local branch* called `remotes/origin/release` which would be delete without `-r`. This might sound confusing but you could just play around, create branches with strange names and look how does it look in `.git/`.

Answer (score 15):

When branches are deleted remotely, you need to prune your local repository — the easiest way to do this is with

```
git fetch -p
```

This will update your local repository with all the changes made to the remote repository, but without updating any of your local branches. After running this,

```
git branch --remote
```

will no longer show the deleted remote branch.

git repositories are complete, whether on your own system or on the server. So when you first clone a repository, you get a complete copy, and your local git “knows” about all the remote branches as well as your local branches. This information isn’t synced automatically, so when your colleague deleted the `release` branch on the server, your local git repository didn’t lose its notion of a remote `release` branch. Syncing with `git fetch` updates all the local information on remote branches so they match the state on the server (strictly speaking, remote repository, wherever that is), but without deleting any local information on remote branches. Pruning with `git fetch -p` (or `git fetch --prune`, or `git remote prune`) removes the local information on remote branches which have been deleted.

Comment: Thanks. "update your local repository with all the changes made to the remote repository, but without updating any of your local branches". What update is that, given that it is not update of my local branches?

Comment: It’s all the remote updates. Your local git repository distinguishes your local branches and the remote branches, but remote branches aren’t magically synced with the server — they exist locally too (as in, stored in your local git repository). Fetching syncs your local repository with the remote repository, and updates the state of remote branches; by default deleted remote branches aren’t removed from the local information on remote branches, `-p` (`--prune`) forces that.

Comment: Thanks. Why didn't  deleting the `release` branch by `git branch -D release` before `git checkout release` make `git checkout release` stop getting the `release` branch?

Comment: Because `git checkout release` will automatically re-create a branch if there is a remote branch with that name.

Comment: By "remote branch", do you mean a branch in my local repository or Github repository? If former, `git branch -D release` has already deleted the `release` branch in my local repository; If latter, a coworker has deleted the `release` branch on GitHub;  So i am still not sure why "will automatically re-create a branch if there is a remote branch with that name"?

Comment: I mean a remote branch as stored in your local repository. You need to understand that there are three sets of branches: your local branches, the remote branches stored in your local repository, and the branches in the remote repository. `git branch -D release` updates the local branches, your colleague updated the branches in the remote repository, but the middle set stayed the same (and still had `release`).

Comment: (1) Did `git branch -D release` already delete the `release` branch in my local repository, so there is no  remote branch with that name `release` in my local repository, so `git checkout release` willnote automatically re-create a branch `release`? (2) Since both GitHub and my local rep already don't have a branch named `release`,from where can `git checkout release` recreate a branch `release` ?

Comment: **No**. `git branch -D release` deleted your **local** branch, it didn’t delete the **remote** branch that git knows about in your local repository. There *is* a remote branch with that name in your local repository. There are **three** sets of branches, you only updated two of them.

Answer (score 3):

Tim: Git is distributed VCS, so when you clone a repo from remote to your local it clones everything (history). 
So when you cloned your repo, it had a branch called release. Since your colleague deleted release branch remotely, till you do a prune `git fetch -p` or delete that branch explicitly your local will have that branch.

Comment: How does this answer differ from the answers already present?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a bit tangential but the perspective of this site might help to understand the general topic of deleting branches:

http://railsware.com/blog/2014/08/11/git-housekeeping-tutorial-clean-up-outdated-branches-in-local-and-remote-repositories/

There is overlap with some of what's already been discussed here but the focus is on housekeeping: deleting branches, remote and local, that are no longer needed in a collaborative environment. In particular the `git branch --merged` command identifies branches that are safe to delete due to being merged to your mainline (or whatever branch you care about). If you're collaborating, some fancier mini scripts like this one will present things in a nice, digestible format with dates and authors.

```
for branch in `comm -12  <(git branch --merged|awk '{print($1)}') <(git branch -r --merged|awk '{print($1)}'|awk -F \/ '{print($2)}')`; do echo -e `git show --format="%ci %cr %an" $branch | head -n 1` \\t$branch; done | sort -r
```

(Unfortunately "nice, digestible" doesn't apply to the formatting of the scripts themselves.)